# jQuery animate() not working in my case when applied on scroll top button

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, scrolltop

When scroll top button is clicked, the animate function doesn't work.
It just follows the link of the anchor.
I have used this code in other project and it works perfectly there.

Edit:
I also tried:
 By removing the href="#"

By giving e.preventDefault in scrollUp click

```js
var scrollUp = $(".scrollTop");

   $(window).scroll(function() {
   var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();

   if (topPos > 100) {
      $(scrollUp).css("opacity", "1");

   } else {
      $(scrollUp).css("opacity", "0");
   }

   });

   $($(scrollUp)).click(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
   }, 800);
   return false;

   });
```

```css
html, body {
   font-size: 95%;
   color: #1a2439;
   background-color: #fafafa;
   line-height: 1.7em;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
   letter-spacing: 0.035em;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollTop">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up scrollTopBtn"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got my silly mistake.
I was using jquery slim build version in the current project and it doesn't support all features.
I switched to jquery full version (compressed production version) and this code runs perfectly now!